# Defining a multidimensional array in excel with calculated values (they're not a constant)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In my Sub I need a multidimensional array for further calculations. But my problem is that I initially don't know the exact length of all my dimensions. Therefore in the first step of my Sub I coded a procedure to calculate every length of the dimension.

```
Sub MultiDimensionalArray()

' Init 
Dim dim1 As Integer 
Dim dim2 As Integer 
Dim dim3 As Integer 
Dim dim4 As Integer

' Calculation of the single dimensions 
'... some calculations with the result 
dim1 = 4 
dim2 = 6 
dim3 = 7 
dim4 = 4

' And now my 4d array 
Dim MyArray(1 To dim1, 1 To dim2, 1 To dim3, 1 To dim4) As String

' And now the further code...

End Sub
```

And like some of you can imagine an error is arising: *Compile error: Constant expression required*

So I have to do something like

```
Const dim1 As Integer = 4
Const dim2 As Integer = 6
Const dim3 As Integer = 7
Const dim4 As Integer = 4

Dim MyArray(1 To dim1, 1 To dim2, 1 To dim3, 1 To dim4) As String
```

for my array.

And this impossible for me because as said above I don't know the value of `dim1` or `dim2` or `dim3` or `dim4` (first I have to do some calculations to get these values).

I found this hint [ReDim existing array with a second dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672300/redim-existing-array-with-a-second-dimension) here on stackoverflow - but to be honest this workaround won't work for me in this specific situation.

Do you have any suggestions how I can solve my *dimensioning-array-issue*?

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Thanks to VBasic2008! With this comment my issue is solved.

Btw. in my opinion it's no *duplicate* because I'm questioning about an array with more than one dimension. Okay both questions can get solved with `ReDim` - but the amount of dimensions thing is not mentioned in any answer (as far as I can assess)...

Comment: Use `ReDim`....

Comment: You don't have to use constants. Use `Dim MyArray() As String: ReDim MyArray(1 To dim1, 1 To dim2, 1 To dim3, 1 To dim4)`. But that's a lot of dimensions. Usually, you need a *jagged* array, an array of arrays. Then each of these arrays can have more arrays and so on. Try to explain what you're trying to do to get some useful advice.

Comment: @VBasic2008 That's exactly what I needed - your code snippet. I always read something that only the last dimension of an array could be redimensionated. Thanks for that workaround.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate. The fact that there are multiple dimensions is irrelevant. But what does it matter anyway, if you got the answer, which is to use `ReDim`? There's no negative effect of your question being closed as a dupe. If you want, feel free to delete the question entirely.